# Cannot figure out how to v-for on a table row (tr) and render a child component that has multiple columns (td)

Tags: vue.js

My code produces the error:

> Component template should contain exactly one root element.

I have this in the parent:

```
<tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <Item :item="item" />
```

And in the Item:

```
<td>
  hello
</td>
<td>
  world
</td>
```

If I wrap that in anything then I get invalid html. I assume that vue never thought it be necessary to include something like `<React.Fragment>` so I need to add 3rd party dependency for this? I'd rather not install yet another dependency for something that should be core functionality.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<Item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" item="item">
```

And just have the table row (tr) be the root element of Item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error since the component template should only have one parent element, so, in order to fix this, you should wrap up the template's content:

```
<template>
     <div>
          <td>hello</td>
          <td>world</td>
     </div>
</template>
```

However, I suggest to do this:

In the parent:

```
<Item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :item="item" />
```

In the child:

```
<template>
     <tr>
          <td>hello</td>
          <td>world</td>
     </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: That is invalid html

Comment: I forgot `:item="item"` in `<Item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :item="item" />`

Answer (score 2):

You should include the `tr` tag in your template then:

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>world</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Then use v-for directly on the component:

```
<Item v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :item="item" />
```